# Выполнение кода в момент закрытия окна php? Возможно вообще такое?

Tags: php, mysql, события

Мне нужно сделать так что бы при закрытии вкладки, окна или другого способа выхода из сессии, на mysql бд отправлялась переменная. Возможно вообще такое? Есть иной способ?

Comment: Если это и можно сделать, то довольно сложно реализовать. Но можно)

Comment: Как? Я просто тут дурью маюсь и хочу что то типо онлайн игры написать на php/mysql)

Comment: А зачем отправлять код при закрытии вкладки?

Comment: js beforeunload + ajax на бек. гуглите вокруг этого. И закройте вопрос, заминусуют и всё-равно закроют.

Comment: @Kirill не надежно.

Comment: какую логику то хотите реализовать, зачем и правда при закрытии окна что-то делать?

Comment: php - не тот язык, на котором вам нужно отслеживать браузерные/фронтовые события, для этого есть самый очевидный js/ts, далее, как уже сказали, отправьте запрос на сервер, как раз к php. Самое очевидное решение.